# Strange xargs Behavior with special characters within variable

Tags: bash, macos, xargs

I'm running into strange behavior with xargs in a bash script where the replacement is not working anymore when placing it in the middle of a variable with special characters. Please see the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

url=https://myhostname.com/endpoint/
parameters="?Policy=1&KeyPairId=aaaaa&Signature=aa~UhFXhFy-DalIcQDq~Hfd-b57cm~~kkKfV6~ly1lapp0Elu1N84WKHh7Y4sjR2saA9cx2gJF8jTEUVsimQ21zBbyQE46-pPHyePAB1bV9nVfZ6euU14ovWyZazd3FyjGaN7qVSA5ntf8RUfUCo7Asc0Gilf0FJzzlMtI38hSWj3wGC-4B-7ANrA__&Key-Pair-Id=YYY"

echo 1 2 3 | xargs -n1 -I{} echo $url{}$parameters -o {}
```

results in:

```
https://myhostname.com/endpoint/{}?Policy=1&KeyPairId=aaaaa&Signature=aa~UhFXhFy-DalIcQDq~Hfd-b57cm~~kkKfV6~ly1lapp0Elu1N84WKHh7Y4sjR2saA9cx2gJF8jTEUVsimQ21zBbyQE46-pPHyePAB1bV9nVfZ6euU14ovWyZazd3FyjGaN7qVSA5ntf8RUfUCo7Asc0Gilf0FJzzlMtI38hSWj3wGC-4B-7ANr -o 1
https://myhostname.com/endpoint/{}?Policy=1&KeyPairId=aaaaa&Signature=aa~UhFXhFy-DalIcQDq~Hfd-b57cm~~kkKfV6~ly1lapp0Elu1N84WKHh7Y4sjR2saA9cx2gJF8jTEUVsimQ21zBbyQE46-pPHyePAB1bV9nVfZ6euU14ovWyZazd3FyjGaN7qVSA5ntf8RUfUCo7Asc0Gilf0FJzzlMtI38hSWj3wGC-4B-7ANr -o 2
https://myhostname.com/endpoint/{}?Policy=1&KeyPairId=aaaaa&Signature=aa~UhFXhFy-DalIcQDq~Hfd-b57cm~~kkKfV6~ly1lapp0Elu1N84WKHh7Y4sjR2saA9cx2gJF8jTEUVsimQ21zBbyQE46-pPHyePAB1bV9nVfZ6euU14ovWyZazd3FyjGaN7qVSA5ntf8RUfUCo7Asc0Gilf0FJzzlMtI38hSWj3wGC-4B-7ANr -o 3
```

Please note the `1` `2` and `3` did not show up but was the literal {} in the endpoint.

I determined it was the parameter because when I removed a few characters, it worked:

```
#!/bin/bash

url=https://myhostname.com/endpoint/
parameters="?Policy=1&KeyPairId=aaaaa&Signature=aa~UhFXhFy-DalIcQDq~Hfd-b57cm~~kkKfV6~ly1lapp0Elu1N84WKHh7Y4sjR2saA9cx2gJF8jTEUVsimQ21zBbyQE46-WyZazd3FyjGaN7qVSA5ntf8RUfUCo7Asc0Gilf0FJzzlMtI38hSWj3wGC-4B-7ANrA__&Key-Pair-Id=YYY"


echo 1 2 3 | xargs -n1 -I{} echo $url{}$parameters -o {}
```

```
https://myhostname.com/endpoint/1?Policy=1&KeyPairId=aaaaa&Signature=aa~UhFXhFy-DalIcQDq~Hfd-b57cm~~kkKfV6~ly1lapp0Elu1N84WKHh7Y4sjR2saA9cx2gJF8jTEUVsimQ21zBbyQE46-WyZazd3FyjGaN7qVSA5ntf8RUfUCo7Asc0Gilf0FJzzlMtI38hSWj3wGC-4B-7ANrA__&Key-Pair-Id=YYY -o 1
https://myhostname.com/endpoint/2?Policy=1&KeyPairId=aaaaa&Signature=aa~UhFXhFy-DalIcQDq~Hfd-b57cm~~kkKfV6~ly1lapp0Elu1N84WKHh7Y4sjR2saA9cx2gJF8jTEUVsimQ21zBbyQE46-WyZazd3FyjGaN7qVSA5ntf8RUfUCo7Asc0Gilf0FJzzlMtI38hSWj3wGC-4B-7ANrA__&Key-Pair-Id=YYY -o 2
https://myhostname.com/endpoint/3?Policy=1&KeyPairId=aaaaa&Signature=aa~UhFXhFy-DalIcQDq~Hfd-b57cm~~kkKfV6~ly1lapp0Elu1N84WKHh7Y4sjR2saA9cx2gJF8jTEUVsimQ21zBbyQE46-WyZazd3FyjGaN7qVSA5ntf8RUfUCo7Asc0Gilf0FJzzlMtI38hSWj3wGC-4B-7ANrA__&Key-Pair-Id=YYY -o 3
```

Note the 1, 2, and 3 is there.

I am on MacOS. This behavior seems to be specific to the xargs on Mac. This will not even run on linux xargs with the flags passed. Would love some suggestions how to make this portable and work on all systems. Thank you.

Comment: On my Mac I get `xargs: command line cannot be assembled, too long` with first example

Comment: The warning `xargs: warning: options --max-args and --replace/-I/-i are mutually exclusive,` is pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin that is the error if you try to run this on linux. That error does not occur on the BSD (MacOS) version of xargs.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `1 2 3`? I looks like you want something like `printf "%s\n" 1 2 3 | xargs -I{} echo "$url{}$parameters" ...`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin They're equivalent. `xargs` splits the input on any whitespace by default.

Comment: I guess it is the *too long* that is making things work in unexplained ways. I thought the whitespace would be sufficient. Thanks. On Linux with the newline and without the `-n1`, I get what looks like the expected `https://myhostname.com/endpoint/1?Policy=1&KeyPa...` then the `.../2?Policy=...` and `...3/?Policy=...`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I isolated the example, the real script pulls data from a file filtering the data with grep before piping it to xargs and curl to download the files.

Comment: There's no good reason to use xargs in this code at all. `for n in 1 2 3; do echo "${url}${n}${parameters}" -o "$n"; done` keeps it simpler and avoids relying on nonstandard behavior (and the POSIX standard for xargs only requires it to recognize your `-I` sigil -- in this case `{}` -- as a complete argument, not when it's a substring of something else).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I tried to isolate the problem; the original script does a grep search in a file and I want to curl the matching results `grep mp4 unformattedfile.txt| xargs ...`; Any idea how to make it not rely on non-standard behavior for that? I have a solution, but it doesn't feel elegant. Would love something that avoids nonstandard behavior.

Comment: @PressingOnAlways, the loop I suggested works fine when you replace `echo` with `curl`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy but how do I get the data into a for loop from grep? `for n in \`grep mp4 unformattedfiile.txt\`; do ... ; done` surely can't work.

Comment: @PressingOnAlways, `while IFS= read -r n; do ...; done < <(grep mp4 unformattedfile.txt)` -- see [BashFAQ #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

Comment: @PressingOnAlways, btw, see also [DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) going into detail on why `for n in ...` is wrong, and [BashPitfalls #56](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#Using_xargs_without_-0) for discussion of why xargs is unsafe without `-0` (or in the GNU case `-d $'\n'`)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy That's awesome! I knew you could use << to read in files, I didn't know you could run that through a command like that. It totally makes sense, just never thought about it before. Thanks!

Comment: @PressingOnAlways, btw, note that `<<` is not a thing (except maybe as a part of heredoc syntax). `<` is one operator, `<( ... )` is another; so the space between the two `<`s is important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the man page:

> ```
> -I replstr
>         Execute utility for each input line, replacing one or more
>         occurrences of replstr in up to replacements (or 5 if no -R flag
>         is specified) arguments to utility with the entire line of input.
>         The resulting arguments, after replacement is done, will not be
>         allowed to grow beyond replsize (or 255 if no -S flag is
>         specified) bytes; this is implemented by concatenating as much of
>         the argument containing replstr as possible, to the constructed
>         arguments to utility, up to replsize bytes.  The size limit does
>         not apply to arguments to utility which do not contain replstr,
>         and furthermore, no replacement will be done on utility itself.
>         Implies -x.
> ```

Your output string is longer that 255 characters, so it doesn't perform the replacement. Add a `-S` option that's large than the maximum possible output string.

```
$ echo 1 2 3 | xargs -n1 -I{} -S 500 echo "$url{}$parameters" -o {}
https://myhostname.com/endpoint/1?Policy=1&KeyPairId=aaaaa&Signature=aa~UhFXhFy-DalIcQDq~Hfd-b57cm~~kkKfV6~ly1lapp0Elu1N84WKHh7Y4sjR2saA9cx2gJF8jTEUVsimQ21zBbyQE46-pPHyePAB1bV9nVfZ6euU14ovWyZazd3FyjGaN7qVSA5ntf8RUfUCo7Asc0Gilf0FJzzlMtI38hSWj3wGC-4B-7ANrA__&Key-Pair-Id=YYY -o 1
https://myhostname.com/endpoint/2?Policy=1&KeyPairId=aaaaa&Signature=aa~UhFXhFy-DalIcQDq~Hfd-b57cm~~kkKfV6~ly1lapp0Elu1N84WKHh7Y4sjR2saA9cx2gJF8jTEUVsimQ21zBbyQE46-pPHyePAB1bV9nVfZ6euU14ovWyZazd3FyjGaN7qVSA5ntf8RUfUCo7Asc0Gilf0FJzzlMtI38hSWj3wGC-4B-7ANrA__&Key-Pair-Id=YYY -o 2
https://myhostname.com/endpoint/3?Policy=1&KeyPairId=aaaaa&Signature=aa~UhFXhFy-DalIcQDq~Hfd-b57cm~~kkKfV6~ly1lapp0Elu1N84WKHh7Y4sjR2saA9cx2gJF8jTEUVsimQ21zBbyQE46-pPHyePAB1bV9nVfZ6euU14ovWyZazd3FyjGaN7qVSA5ntf8RUfUCo7Asc0Gilf0FJzzlMtI38hSWj3wGC-4B-7ANrA__&Key-Pair-Id=YYY -o 3
```

Also remember to quote variables to prevent word splitting and globbing.

Comment: Thank you! I thought it had something to do with the special characters in the string. This solved the issue.

Comment: When in doubt, read the documentation.

Comment: Mind, it's perhaps worth noting that the support for `...{}...` is an extension; POSIX only requires xargs to recognize the `-I` sigil as a complete argument -- the other behavior is explicitly permitted, but not mandated.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Also, I think this is specific to the BSD version of `xargs` that MacOS uses, I don't see similar wording in the Linux man page.

Answer (score 0):

I ultimately went with @Charles Duffy's solution in the comments. It is best to bypass xargs altogether and use something that is compatible both on Linux and MacOS/BSD.

```
url=https://myhostname.com/endpoint/
parameters="?Policy=1&KeyPairId=aaaaa&Signature=aa~UhFXhFy-DalIcQDq~Hfd-b57cm~~kkKfV6~ly1lapp0Elu1N84WKHh7Y4sjR2saA9cx2gJF8jTEUVsimQ21zBbyQE46-pPHyePAB1bV9nVfZ6euU14ovWyZazd3FyjGaN7qVSA5ntf8RUfUCo7Asc0Gilf0FJzzlMtI38hSWj3wGC-4B-7ANrA__&Key-Pair-Id=YYY"

while IFS= read -r line; do
  echo "${url}${line}${parameters}" -o downloads/$line
done < <(printf "1.mp4\n2.mp4\n3.mp4\n")
```

Returns expected value:

```
https://myhostname.com/endpoint/1.mp4?Policy=1&KeyPairId=aaaaa&Signature=aa~UhFXhFy-DalIcQDq~Hfd-b57cm~~kkKfV6~ly1lapp0Elu1N84WKHh7Y4sjR2saA9cx2gJF8jTEUVsimQ21zBbyQE46-pPHyePAB1bV9nVfZ6euU14ovWyZazd3FyjGaN7qVSA5ntf8RUfUCo7Asc0Gilf0FJzzlMtI38hSWj3wGC-4B-7ANrA__&Key-Pair-Id=YYY -o downloads/1.mp4
https://myhostname.com/endpoint/2.mp4?Policy=1&KeyPairId=aaaaa&Signature=aa~UhFXhFy-DalIcQDq~Hfd-b57cm~~kkKfV6~ly1lapp0Elu1N84WKHh7Y4sjR2saA9cx2gJF8jTEUVsimQ21zBbyQE46-pPHyePAB1bV9nVfZ6euU14ovWyZazd3FyjGaN7qVSA5ntf8RUfUCo7Asc0Gilf0FJzzlMtI38hSWj3wGC-4B-7ANrA__&Key-Pair-Id=YYY -o downloads/2.mp4
https://myhostname.com/endpoint/3.mp4?Policy=1&KeyPairId=aaaaa&Signature=aa~UhFXhFy-DalIcQDq~Hfd-b57cm~~kkKfV6~ly1lapp0Elu1N84WKHh7Y4sjR2saA9cx2gJF8jTEUVsimQ21zBbyQE46-pPHyePAB1bV9nVfZ6euU14ovWyZazd3FyjGaN7qVSA5ntf8RUfUCo7Asc0Gilf0FJzzlMtI38hSWj3wGC-4B-7ANrA__&Key-Pair-Id=YYY -o downloads/3.mp4
```

The details I left out was the `printf "1.mp4\n2.mp4\n3.mp4\n"` was actually a grep command which I was easily able to replace, and the echo was a call to curl.

I highly recommend using this method over trying to fuss with making it work with xargs. It is much more straightforward and you do not have to worry about the different versions of xargs. Utilizing [process substitution](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution) was the most straightforward cross-platform compatible methodology.